# Error while converting continuous data to categorical data in Logistic Regression

Tags: casting, data-science, logistic-regression, modeling

I am using Logistic regression over my dataset which has its target variable in 0s and 1s. I used .replace() function and replaced them accordingly.

```
> data['target']=data['target'].replace({0:"No",1:"yes"})
```

The code ran fine. But when I am modelling the data,

```
model_log=sm.Logit(data['target'],data.iloc[:,2:]).fit()
```

it is showing the below error:

> ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input
>   data with np.asarray(data).

Comment: Logit requires that the dependent (target) variable is numeric (integer or float) in {0, 1} or float in the interval [0, 1] for quasi-maximum likelihood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you select X data using [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html),it is return a pandas dataframe.[According to statsmodel documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit.html),logit expect to X and y to be array_like. You need to cast the dataframe to required data type.You can use [to_numpy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) method to convert dataframe to numpy array.

```
model_log=sm.Logit(data['target'].astype(float),data.iloc[:,2:].to_numpy()).fit()
```